# stop OSX from interception option/alt/meta key combos

Tags: macos, osx-lion, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, utf

I've googled around and can't figure this out: How do I get OSX to stop intercepting alt/option/meta key combos and inserting fancy utf characters instead of passing the key combo to the app? Say I'm in Emacs, usually M-g M-g is bound to goto-line. On OSX lion it inserts ©. This happens for most alt+ bindings

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What version of Emacs are you using? I have GNU Emacs 23.4.1 on OS X Lion, and the option key does behave as Emacs meta.

Make sure you don't have anything in your Emacs init file that configures the option key to behave differently. Confirm by starting Emacs without loading your init file. From the terminal, type:

/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -Q

Comment: It definitely wasn't anything in my init file. I ended up swapping command and alt/option for my MBP keyboard under System Preferences > Keyboard > modifier keys so that now it feels like a normal keyboard. Sometime between doing this, upgrading to mavericks and possibly upgrading emacs the issue went away, I'm not sure why.